# failing to use req.params in api angular 4 mean to get data from mongoose database

Tags: angular, parameters, get, httpclient

Using postman I am able to reach the api and find the data I am looking for. 
However when I try the client with the params function it doesn't give any errors. But it doesn't seem to do anything, also doesn't give a Get/200 not sure if this is always the case. 
So I use a button to fire the link that fires the get request and I see no get/200 requests. In the browser there are also no errors. 
I literally gone over all variations with req.params.btc and tried using req.query. 
I read that you can't have multiple params with the set function so therefore I am using the params.append.

Spend hours and hours on this, I really hope someone can help me out with this one. I am using HttpClient angular 4+ and I am basically trying to get data from the mongoose server using a parameter ID that I want to send with HTTP to select the data on the api/mongoose

```
AUTH-SERVICE.TS
readonly ROOT_URL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/findData';
var params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('key', 'value1');
params = params.append('key', 'value2');


this.http.get(this.ROOT_URL ,{ params })

.do(console.log)

    .map(data => data.send (data))
 }


API.JS
router.get('/findData:btc', function (req, res) {

Coin.findOne ({ 'coinCode' :  mongojs.ObjectID(req.params.btc) },  
function    (err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
if (result) {
    res.json(result)
} else {
    res.send(JSON.stringify({
        error : 'Error'
    }))
}
})
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add / in your url before the params like, '/findData/:btc'